# Change recyclerview item background when swiped

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Hi i am showing vertical list using `recycler view` and i am using a gradient background for `recycler view`.I am deleting items in `recycler view` when they are swiped left or right using `ItemTouchHelper`.

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            mRecyclerAdapter.removeStock(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            if(actionState!=ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE){
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
        }
    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Here i am changing recycler view item background to light grey when item is swiped but i want the original background back when recycler view item goes back to idle state i.e i want that gradient background back.
Recylerview xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
tools:context=".ui.StockFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:startColor="#FF18181F"
    android:endColor="#FF27354D"
    android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can try inside of [`onSelectedChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onSelectedChanged(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20int)). Alternatively, perhaps you can override [`clearView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#clearView(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) and do the change there after calling the superclass method.

**EDIT**

Having read the documentation more, I now think `onSelectedChanged()` is the correct place to change the background both for when the item starts swiping *and* when it returns to idle. Check that the `viewHolder` is not null and then check the `actionState` for what to change the background to.

I think `onChildDraw()` is not the right place to do this because it is already in the drawing phase and changing the view's background there will probably cause another re-draw.

Comment: hi now i using this method but before changing background of my viewholder item i want to save its current background color...how to do that?

Comment: I am using viewholder.itemView.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor() and saving it in class variable but when i am using it in clearView() method i am getting null exception