# How to change RecyclerView item color on Swipe?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make `recyclerView` item change color on swipe so it's will be highlited because on swipe i open an `AlertDialog` so the person will recognize which one item he is changing.

But my main issue is that when i try to change the background color by using

```
viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cc0000"));
```

Nothing is heppening, here is my full code from the builder of `recyclerView`

```
public void buildTopRecyclerView(){

    mRecyclerViewTOP = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mRecyclerViewTOP.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    exampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(itemCassas);
    mRecyclerViewTOP.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerViewTOP.setAdapter(exampleAdapter);

  //  onSwipe();

    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                customAllertDelete(position);
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cc0000"));
                exampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                customAllertQuantity(position);
            }

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerViewTOP);

}
```

And here is also the Adapter code if it could be usefull

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ItemCassa> mExampleList;


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerlist_item,parent,false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }

    ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ItemCassa> exampleList){
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemCassa item = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getBtnName());
        holder.qta.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuant()));
        holder.imp.setText(String.valueOf((new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(item.getPrice()))));

        if(position % 2 == 0 ){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"));
            holder.desc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"));
            holder.qta.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"));
            holder.imp.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"));

        }else if(position % 2 == 1){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
            holder.desc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
            holder.qta.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
            holder.imp.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView qta;
        public TextView imp;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            qta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qta);
            imp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Imp);


        }
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mExampleList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }




}
```

Here is the gif that "explain" a bit what i'm trying to do, as you can see on swipe it's open an AlertDialog and turn back the selected item, but now i would color that selected item background until the user make a choose in the AlertDialog

[image]

Comment: this piece of code, you are using in activity right ?

Comment: @Umair yes it's the code from my activity

Comment: Ok. I think you are not getting the position of item. It will be good if you take position directly from the adapter.

Comment: @Umair actually i'm getting position because i'm able to delete from the alertDialog the item onSwipe position :\

Comment: by looking at your code, you are trying to delete an item through alert dialog and when deleted it turns the item background color to red bacground. am i right ?

Comment: @Umair actually on swipe it will open an AlertDialog in which it will ask the user if he want to delete the RecyclerView and when the AlertDialog is up i would set that the item he selected and swiped will become red so the user will know that he is going or not to delete that item

Comment: yes you can do that too and more good is make a method in your adapter and through that method you can do communication with your activity onSwipe.

Comment: Another approach is when you are swiping your item, draw an animation on that, What it will do is it will color your empty space of swipe item to red so user will know that it is swiping that particular item.

Comment: Take a look at this question too maybe it will help. Further more I can provide you some code to give you the idea how you do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770913/change-recyclerview-item-background-when-swiped

Comment: @Umair actually by changing the color of also the desc/qta/imp hasn't had any effect, i've added to the code a GIF that show my activity

Comment: Ok I understood let me post an answer for you.

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using like this:

First of all in your onSwiped method call your adapter's method and pass the required parameters.

```
  @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            int swipedPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            YourAdapter adapter = (YourAdapter) rlCartList.getAdapter();


                adapter.remove(swipedPosition); // I was removing items so you
                                                  can change the name of method as you like
        }
```

Now in your adapter do something like this:

```
  public void remove(int position) {

        YourModel item = cartItems.get(position);

        if (cartItems.contains(item)) {
            ViewHolder.tvItemName.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

One more thing is you will need to make your textView or the view you are assigning the background to `Static`. And I have tested this code it's running fine in my project the background of textView changes on swipe.

Tell me if you need further assistance. And also one more thing you can use your alert dialog in adapter too :)